# controlling iframe margin and source from js (js inside iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I have an Iframe. What I want to do is to change the src and margins of the iframe from the javascript which is included in the document already open in iframe.

I have already tried the following but no use -

```
document.popiframe.document.body.innerHTML="blah";
document.getElementById( 'popiframe' ).setAttribute( 'src', '' );
$('.popiframe').attr('src', "about:blank");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: whats with **about:blank** ?

Comment: about:blank makes the page to be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iframe is a window in a window, you change the page displayed there (= not the src attribute) like you would change it in any other window :

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

changing the margin around the iframe isn't possible from where I see it...

Comment: hi..thanks for helping. Your solution worked but now I realize that I don't want to change the URL as I still want the JS on the page to work..I just want to make the iframe look blank.. so can I somehow change HTML?

Comment: with a CSS rule like body {display:none;} , for example